# How to remove the Azure Container portion of an url

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I am moving from AWS S3 to Azure Blob. I can access my photos at S3 with a URL like photos.example.com/image1.jpg .  I can point photos.example.com to the azure blob, but I need to append the container name, to access the photos.
In a summary on AWS, I can access the photos with a URL like:

photos.example.com/image1.jpg

But on Azure since everything goes under a container, to access the same photo, I need to add the container to the URL.

photos.example.com/**container**/image1.jpg

I am looking for options to eliminate the container name from the URL, so I can just change the CNMAE from AWS to Azure.

Is this possible by using: Azure CDN, Azure functions, change a configuration on the Azure storage, or any other method.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After further research it's possible.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/working-with-the-root-container

Comment: This is correct. However please note that you will not be able to create virtual folders inside `$root` container. So if you have blob named like `images/image1.jpg`, you will not be able to use this blob container.